# How to install latest Boost version on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, bootstrapping, b2

I had Boost installed with

```
apt-get install libboost-dev-all
```

but version of Boost installed via this command was 1.54.
I tried to install 1.60 using tutorial from boost.org via `bootstrap` and `b2` using default options.But figured that I need a bit earlier version, so i tried 1.59, 1.57, etc.. All to default location.
So now I have no idea what boost do I have, because in /usr/local/lib rests files with 1.60 postfix even after 1.57 installation(using tutorial from boost.org).
I tried to compile it in different directory and it was builded fine.

So I have two question:
1. How to rip off all this mess with different version of boost installed to default location.
2. How to make Ubuntu use Boost build that lies not in default location for making some project.

Answer (score 1):

Using sudo apt-get purge  will remove , all it's versions and all of it's config files that are not located in "Home" (~).

You will have to remove config files in your home directory manually.